# Checking website status in .NET

Tags: .net

I need to build a .NET function that tests to see if a specific website is online.  What is the best way to do this?  I was going to simply ping the site, but I wondered if there was a more accurate method.

Thanks!

Comment: Ping isn't the best solution because it only checks to see if the machine is up or not. The status of the web server is still in question.

Comment: Excellant timing for your question - I was asked about doing this recently!  Thanks.

Comment: I figured that ping was a sub-par method, which is why I asked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I always use this for checking if websites are working correctly:

```
public bool IsWebsiteOnline(string url)
{
    try
    {
        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        myReq.Timeout = 10000;

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse()) 
        {
           return response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the way to go, since not all servers will respond to a PING request

Comment: You should use. Using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)myreq.GetResponse()) { .. } or Close the HttpWebResponse

Comment: +1 Nice, I've never needed to do this.. but if I ever did this good.

Answer (score 1):

Never assume the ability to ping a site gives you any information about the status of it, other than the box is turned on and happens to respond to pings.

Answer (score 0):

A ping checks that the server responds.  However the web app part could be down, the db could be done, etc etc.

SO writing a request for HTTP data from the URL, and :

1) check the status code response is OK

2) check there was content at all (non empty page)

*3) if you really want to be clever, depending on requirements, validate the data returned - ie compare part of it for a particular string.

*but at a bare minimum I'd suggest 1 and 2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Watin](http://watin.sourceforge.net/) to perform small tasks and thereby judge if the site is working properly.

Watin allows you to test functionality as well.
(Some code stolen from their site)

```
public void SearchForWatiNOnGoogle()
{
 using (IE ie = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
 {
  ie.TextField(Find.ByName("q")).TypeText("WatiN");
  ie.Button(Find.ByName("btnG")).Click();

  Assert.IsTrue(ie.ContainsText("WatiN"));
 }
}
```